# No examples after join in Rapidminer

Tags: rapidminer

Hi I am working on an assignment but I have a problem. 
There are 2 datasets, the first has some flight information and the second has weather information. I want to predict whether a flight will depart with a delay of 15 minutes or more (using a decision tree). I have done the following:

- Import flight data -- select attributes -- split data -- parse numbers

I selected the following attributes: day, dep_delay_15, dep_time_planned, dest_airport, dest_city, month, origin_airport, origin_city, origin_id and year. 
After this I used split to split the dep_time_planned attribute into 2 parts (the first with the hour, the second with the minute) and I've parsed this.

- Import weather data -- select attributes

Here I selected all of the attributes. 
After this I have joined these datasets, but after the join all of the examples are gone (the attributes are still there). I have tried everything: left, right, inner and outer join. The key attribute couples I have made are:

- origin_id, airport_id
- day, day
- month, month
- dep_time_planned_1, hour
- year, year

Can somebody help me out?

Comment: I found out that the problem was not with the join, but it happened after the join. I used a filter which filtered too much out. I was confused, because after the join it already said it was empty, except it was not. Thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 0):

without knowing the exact content of the attributes it's hard to say what the exact problem is.

In general when you want to perform a join, you want to couple two data sets with a common ID attribute (or column). The difference between the difference types of join is, how the pairs of IDs are handled.
Most commonly (and fitting for your case) is a inner join, where you only want those pairs where the ID matches.
So my guess would be an inner join between *origin_id* and *airport_id*, but of course those two columns need the same format and content (like "Boston", "Berlin", or a common number format).
When they are not the same, then also no matches can be found and the result is empty.

From a RapidMiner perspective, you should make sure the two attributes have the same data type and obviously are not empty after your pre-processing.

For general questions about RapidMiner and its usage, you can also post questions in the RapidMiner community:
https://community.rapidminer.com/

Best,
David

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using Multiply function which will consolidate 2 tables into one and It would be great if you provide a link to data set or any screenshots of the data just to know about the data. as rapid miner is completely data type dependent.
Thank you.